# calculate my Zakath

Tags: zakat

I have gold Jewellery with me moms and wife's total value of 214000 dollars. All the gold weights almost 4500 grams roughly and having it with me for more than five years now. Tell me how many grams to deduct each year in my calculations cz I pay 2.5% in cash and not in gold.

Second point is I have a mix of currencies as saving for more than 6 years and not even touched it all sum up and equivalent to 78000 usd. Tell me how to pay zakath each year by deducting the paying amount from the total.

Third point is I have many building rented out and I get total rent per annum is 36000 dollars.

Fourth point is I'm a Jewellery shop owner and I have gold which comes equivalent of 100000 dollars for business purposes.

Fifth point I bought a house more than one year back which I couldn't pay fully and still I owe the house owner 42000 dollar.

Sixth point is my personal expenses per month is 2700 dollars which included
My expenses are as following= school fees, business premises rent which I pay to the owner, vehicle insurance, electricity bill, water bill, mobile and land phone bill, salary for employees, salary for home servants, luxury vehicle tax, house tax, business shop tax, other buildings premises tax, credit card statements, parents and wife pocket money and house groceries items everything's included. ( I didn't include the business income tax which we pay for the Goverment for our business every year and I'm a tax payer I pay 1000 dollars every year for the Goverment as well ). Let me know whether i should include the income tax or not.

My main question is how much exactly should I pay zakath for the year 2015 by taking all the six points to consideration. The total amount.  Pls let me know. It would be a great help. Pls reply in detail and very clearly so that I'll understand and pay correctly and Allah will accept my deeds.

Answer (score 1):

`I have gold Jewellery with me moms and wife's total value of 214000 dollars. All the gold weights almost 4500 grams roughly and having it with me for more than five years now. Tell me how many grams to deduct each year in my calculations cz I pay 2.5% in cash and not in gold.`

According to [Zakat Calculator](http://www.zakat.org/donate/zakat-calculator/?gclid=CIPc2b6j4MYCFVGAaQod3GoBBA#), you owe $5350 for that since the zakat is on the value of the gold if it meets Nisab.

`Second point is I have a mix of currencies as saving for more than 6 years and not even touched it all sum up and equivalent to 78000 usd. Tell me how to pay zakath each year by deducting the paying amount from the total.`

According to [Zakat Calculator](http://www.zakat.org/donate/zakat-calculator/?gclid=CIPc2b6j4MYCFVGAaQod3GoBBA#), you owe $1950 for that.

`Third point is I have many building rented out and I get total rent per annum is 36000 dollars.`

Is that money saved? If that money is spent, you do not need to pay Zakah, you only pay Zakah once the `حول` comes around (1 year from the day you have it). If this money is indeed saved (not included in the other calculations) you will need to pay according to [Zakat Calculator](http://www.zakat.org/donate/zakat-calculator/?gclid=CIPc2b6j4MYCFVGAaQod3GoBBA#), you owe $900 for that.

`Fourth point is I'm a Jewellery shop owner and I have gold which comes equivalent of 100000 dollars for business purposes.`

According to [Hidya Foundation](http://www.hidaya.org/publications/zakat-information/business-merchandise-inventory), and many other scholars that money is taxable. Just make sure that the value is what you paid, not what it might sell for. If it is bought for $100,000 indeed, then according to Zakat Calculator][3](http://www.zakat.org/donate/zakat-calculator/?gclid=CIPc2b6j4MYCFVGAaQod3GoBBA#), you owe $2500 for that.

`Fifth point I bought a house more than one year back which I couldn't pay fully and still I owe the house owner 42000 dollar.`

According to many [scholars](http://islamqa.info/ar/22426), debit has nothing to do with Zakah. If you have 100,000 and you paid out the 42,000 for debts, you still have to pay Zakah for the remaining 58,000. However, when the `حول` comes if you still have that money you still need to pay the entire Zakah on the total amount.

`Sixth point is my personal expenses per month is 2700 dollars which included My expenses are as following= school fees, business premises rent which I pay to the owner, vehicle insurance, electricity bill, water bill, mobile and land phone bill, salary for employees, salary for home servants, luxury vehicle tax, house tax, business shop tax, other buildings premises tax, credit card statements, parents and wife pocket money and house groceries items everything's included. ( I didn't include the business income tax which we pay for the Goverment for our business every year and I'm a tax payer I pay 1000 dollars every year for the Goverment as well ). Let me know whether i should include the income tax or not.`

I do not understand that last part, are you asking if you have to pay taxes for tax refunds, if so the case is yes (see above calculator).